# How to move a specific element?

Tags: html, css

An element won't move to my intended position. I want to have some white space between the right of "Register" and the browser but don't know how to do it. I have tried padding but it seem to be kind of wrong thinking.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.firstpart {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30vh;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar-left {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.badge {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstpart">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="navbar-left">ABOUT</li>
      <li class="navbar-left">CONTACT</li>
      <li class="navbar-left">FAQS</li>
      <div class="navbar-right badge">
        <li>REGISTER</li>
      </div>
      <li class="navbar-right">SIGN IN</li>
      <li class="navbar-right">MANAGE BOOKING</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `div` element cannot be the child of a `ul` element; only `li` elements can be.

Comment: Give the `<li>` in question a class or ID and give it some padding/margin. Don't stuff a `<div>` into your `<ul>` - you're gonna confuse browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
.navbar {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

You can also remove the div inside of your unordered list as this isn't valid HTML. Replace it with:

```
<li class="navbar-right badge">REGISTER</li>
```

Code (open in "Full page" view as otherwise "Manage Booking" gets wrapped):

```css
/* Add this */
.navbar {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.firstpart{
    background-color:#eee;
    height: 30vh;
}
.navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
.navbar-left{
    float: left;    
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
.navbar-right{
    float: right;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.badge{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    height: 35px;
    width: 80px;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="firstpart">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="navbar-left">ABOUT</li>
            <li class="navbar-left">CONTACT</li>
            <li class="navbar-left">FAQS</li>
            <li class="navbar-right badge">REGISTER</li> <!-- Use an li element instead -->
            <li class="navbar-right">SIGN IN</li>
            <li class="navbar-right">MANAGE BOOKING</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply set a width for .navbar div to say,  98%

```
.navbar {
width:98%;
}
```